# How to update a cell slider's value when the cell's button tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view cell and it has two views. One is a button and the other one is a horizontal slider. What I want to do is I want to play a track when a cell's button tapped and once the track begins to play the slider's value should be increased.

When the play button tapped I need to access the UI slider and update it's value. Here's what I've tried;

Button tap:

```
   @IBAction func playPreviewButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
       playPreviewSound(fileName: fileName)
       setPausePreviewSoundButtonImage(button: sender)
   }
```

Play sound func:

```
  private func playPreviewSound(fileName: String) {
            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "mp3")
            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
                player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)
                guard let player = player else { return }
                player.play()
                setIsPreviewPlaying(state: true)
                
                let selectedIndexPath = cellIndexPathDict[fileName]!.indexPath
                
                let asset = AVAsset(url: url!)
                let audioDuration = asset.duration
                let audioDurationSeconds = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(audioDuration))
                
                getCellByIndexPath(indexPath: selectedIndexPath).previewSoundSlider.maximumValue = audioDurationSeconds
                timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(updateSliderWithTimer), userInfo: ["slider": getCellByIndexPath(indexPath: selectedIndexPath).previewSoundSlider], repeats: true)
                
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

```
    private func getCellByIndexPath (indexPath: IndexPath) -> BackStageCollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: BackStageCollectionViewCell.REUSE, for: indexPath) as! BackStageCollectionViewCell
        setCellInstances(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath)
        print("cell title; ", cell.processorNameLabel.text!) // here, the title always the default title. 
        return cell
    }
```

Timer func:

```
   @objc private func updateSliderWithTimer(slider: UISlider) {
       let userInfo = timer.userInfo as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
       let slider: UISlider = (userInfo["slider"] as! UISlider)
       print(slider.maximumValue) // here, the max value is always 1
       slider.value += 0.5
   }
```

How I access the cell? I created a dictionary;

```
   private var cellIndexPathDict: [String: CellIndexModel] = [:]

   struct CellIndexModel {
       var indexPath : IndexPath
   }
```

Push to the dic on cell creation:

UICollectionViewDelegate extention:

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: BackStageCollectionViewCell.REUSE, for: indexPath) as! BackStageCollectionViewCell
            
        setCellInstances(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath)
            
        let gearsGroup = listGearsGroups.object(at: indexPath.section) as! GearsGroup
        let gear = gearsGroup.listGears.object(at: indexPath.row) as! BaseGear
            
        let mod : CellIndexModel = CellIndexModel(indexPath: indexPath)
        cellIndexPathDict[gear.previewSoundFile as String] = mod
            
        cell.playPreviewButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(playPreviewButtonTapped(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.playPreviewButton.accessibilityLabel = gear.previewSoundFile as String?
            
        return cell
   }
```

Basically I'm creating a dictionary to store the cell index path and trying to access it in the tap function but I only get the default values. Not the selected ones.

How can I access and update the cell when the button tapped?
I just started to learn Swift, so an explanation would be awesome! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because of the cell reuse mechanism, when you use

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: BackStageCollectionViewCell.REUSE, for: indexPath) as! BackStageCollectionViewCell
```

in most cases，you will not get the cell of that indexPath you seen.

its state belongs to one of cells in the object pool.

perhaps you get the new created cell, and its state is default.

---

**The solution is typical:**

when your play sound button gets clicked, you can get its indexPath accordingly.

then you can access the value of `audioPlayer.currentTime`,

reload the relevant cell.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      // configure the slide value here
}
```

call this to reload

```
collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
```

usually we want to update the cell's value, we don't handle the cell directly，

we record the value of cell's property, then configure the cell updated by reloading.

I name the pattern **mark & config**

---

**other tip one:**

often times, we don't use

```
 @objc private func updateSliderWithTimer(slider: UISlider) {
       let userInfo = timer.userInfo as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
       let slider: UISlider = (userInfo["slider"] as! UISlider)
       print(slider.maximumValue) // here, the max value is always 1
       slider.value += 0.5
   }
```

we use

```
@objc private func updateSliderWithTimer(slider: UISlider) {
           
           let slider: UISlider = (userInfo["slider"] as! UISlider)
           slider.value = Float(audioPlayer.currentTime)
       }
```

we can access the current player audio play time,

it is better to use the exact time, instead of the approximate time.

---

**other tip 2:**

usually we don't use

```
private func getCellByIndexPath (indexPath: IndexPath) -> BackStageCollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: BackStageCollectionViewCell.REUSE, for: indexPath) as! BackStageCollectionViewCell
        //...
        return cell
    }
```

we use

```
 private func getCellByIndexPath (indexPath: IndexPath) -> BackStageCollectionViewCell? {
        if collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.contains(indexPath){
             // ...
             return collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? BackStageCollectionViewCell
        }else{
             return nil
        }
    }
```

because collectionView's cell reuse, if you can not see the cell, the cell is not existed.

and for user interface, if the cell is not seen, the cell is of no use to the user.

Comment: `return collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? BackStageCollectionViewCell` did the trick. Thank you!